# Bitwise Angular Expression not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a basic ng-show expression as follows:

```
ng-show="((message.status & messageStatus.Spam) != 0)"
```

However, this fails with the following msg:  **"Token '&' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 18 of the expression"**.

Does Angular support bitwise operations, or do I need to write a function to evaluate something as simple as that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the angularjs github buglist: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2838

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression
"Angular Expressions vs. JS Expressions
It might be tempting to think of Angular view expressions as JavaScript expressions, but that is not entirely correct, since Angular does not use a JavaScript eval() to evaluate expressions."

You can use a filter to achieve the effect as such:

```
angular.module('project', [])
.filter('bitwiseAnd', function () {
    return function (firstNumber, secondNumber) {
        return ((parseInt(firstNumber, 10) & parseInt(secondNumber, 10)) === parseInt(secondNumber, 10));
    // return firstNumber % secondNumber > 0
    };
});
```

Comment: I've written a small module for bitwise operation. Check [angular-bitwise-filter][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/lborgav/angular-bitwise-filter

Comment: This doesn't work if the second number is greater than the first. Eg "1 & 9" should also equate to true. Should be instead "return ((parseInt(firstNumber, 10) & parseInt(secondNumber, 10)) > 0)"

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't support according to the [doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Thought it mentioned `'|'` on the doc but don't get confused, `'|'` is not bitwise `OR` it is Angularjs's `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use */% with prime numbers instead of |&^ with bits

I am ussing this expresions:

```
ng-class="{'active':(filter% 2 )}"
ng-click="filter = filter % 2  ? filter * 2 : filter / 2"  
ng-class="{'light':(filter % 2)}" class="fa fa-eye"
```

With the prime numbers 2, 3 and 5

you must start with `$scope.filter=1`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the statement. Already lost a couple of hours until I realized it does not work :)

Here is my workaround:

```
ng-show="((message.status & messageStatus.Spam) != 0)"
```

will become something like:

```
ng-show="(bitwise(message.status, messageStatus.Spam) != 0)"
...
$scope.bitwise = function(n1, n2){
  return n1 & n2;
}
```

Works perfect for me!